# Library Version Mismatch (C++ HDF5 Windows)

Tags: c++, windows, version, hdf5, mismatch

When trying to run a simple program using the hdf5-file format i get these messages and the program crashes:

[image]
[image]

I found posts to other problems like this, but most of them refer to linux and python. I use **C++** (Qt Creator) and **Windows** (Windows 7 64bit) with the MSVC17 64bit Compiler, so these solutions dont work for me.

I don't understand why this occurs, because i simply donwloaded the HDF5 version 1.10.2 and installed it, i don't know why it says something about the version 1.8.15. Where could this come from?

I guess "*library version*" (1.8.15) is the version of my `hdf5.lib` file, right?
What does "*header version*" (1.10.2) mean? I simply `#include <hdf5.h>` and `#include <H5Cpp.h>` in the `main.cpp` and added paths in the `hdf5_test_2.pro` (my project) file.

**Here is my code:**

hdf5_test.pro:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

win32: LIBS += -L'C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.10.2/lib/' -lhdf5 -lhdf5_cpp -lhdf5_hl_cpp

INCLUDEPATH += 'C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.10.2/include'
DEPENDPATH += 'C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.10.2/include'

win32:!win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += 'C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.10.2/lib/libhdf5.lib'
else:win32-g++: PRE_TARGETDEPS += 'C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.10.2/lib/liblibhdf5.a'
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <hdf5.h>
#include <H5Cpp.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace H5;

int main()
{
    hid_t   file_id;
    herr_t  status;

    file_id = H5Fcreate("file.h5", H5F_ACC_TRUNC, H5P_DEFAULT, H5P_DEFAULT);
    status = H5Fclose(file_id);

    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The code example i tried to use comes from [High Level Introduction to HDF5](https://support.hdfgroup.org/HDF5/Tutor/HDF5Intro.pdf) (Pages 16/17).

---

### Solved (meaning next error)

I think i solved the problem: There was another Version of HDF5 installed (1.8.15) on the system (the one who used this PC before me installed it).

I told my programm to link my lib (1.10.2) and passed the path, but somehow he found the 1.8.15 version previously installed. I now told my program to link the old version and it worked.

My `hdf5_test_2.pro` (my project) looks now like this:

```
TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle
CONFIG -= qt

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

win32: LIBS += -LC:/Anaconda2/Library/lib/ -lhdf5 -lhdf5_cpp

INCLUDEPATH += C:/Anaconda2/Library/include
DEPENDPATH += C:/Anaconda2/Library/include
```

Nice so far, but i get these two warnings now:

[image]

Any ideas, what that means?

Comment: A good start would be to run [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on your compiled program, to find out which hdf5.dll it is loading. As you are on windows, keep in mind that first the directory of the binary is scanned, and after that every directory in `%PATH%`.

Comment: @Botje i trid to use Dependency Walker to figure out what version of the dll is loaded, but honestly this looks only like a bunch of numbers for me. Could you link a guide how to find that out with the tool?

Comment: Load your compiled .exe into dependency walker, find hdf5.dll in the middle pane (the one with module as the first column). Now click view -> full paths. The full path should be displayed. Alternatively, do view ->collapse all, and click the [+] next to your .exe in the TOP pane. It should show the direct dependencies, among which hdf5.dll. Now click full paths again to see the full path.

Comment: Consider vcpkg.